# R define simple mathematical operators in a dataframe

Tags: r, function

I have a data.frame that has a variable name and operation to be done for that variable on some other dataframe. The operation is either taking a mean, sum or length

```
ref.df <- data.frame(variable = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
                     operation = c('mean', 'sum', 'length'), stringsAsFactors = F)

full.df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(20),
                      b = rnorm(20),
                      c = rnorm(20))
  
  
for(r in 1:nrow(ref.df)){
    
    rowRef <- ref.df[r, ]
    
    rowRef
    # variable operation
    #  a      mean
    
    # this says in the full.df, take the mean of `a`, or sum `b` or 
    # take the length of `c`. I tried this
    
    rowRef$operation(full.df[rowRef$variable])
    
    # Error: attempt to apply non-function 
  }
```

What's the best way to do this? The reason I am specifying the operation in a `ref.df` because I would like to change whether I want to a mean or a sum or a length of a particular variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's a 1-to-1 pairing of column-to-function, it's easily enough to `mapply` across them.

```r
out1 <- mapply(function(col, fun) match.fun(fun)(full.df[[col]]),
               ref.df$variable, ref.df$operation)
out1
#          a          b          c 
# -0.2375602 -3.4030162 20.0000000 
sapply(out1, class)
#         a         b         c 
# "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
```

If for some reason you need to preserve class across them (perhaps you need `"length"` to remain an integer), then you can use `Map`, which always returns a `list`:

```r
out2 <- Map(function(col, fun) match.fun(fun)(full.df[[col]]), ref.df$variable, ref.df$operation)
out2
# $a
# [1] -0.2375602
# $b
# [1] -3.403016
# $c
# [1] 20
sapply(out2, class)
#         a         b         c 
# "numeric" "numeric" "integer"
```